# UWP builds fails on Azure Pipelines VS17 agent about ValueTuple while it builds on my machine

Tags: uwp, azure-pipelines, c#-7.0

My UWP app uses some C# 7 tuples.
It builds on my machine (both in Debug and Release mode). Yet on Azure Pipelines windows agent it doesn't.

The error is:

Reference to type 'ValueTuple<,,>' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found

I first thought, let's add `System.ValueTuple` nuget package but the error remained. Note that I do restore nuget packages on the agent before buidling with nuget 5.1.0.

Update:

I created a new Hello World UWP app, added a class using a `ValueTuple` and it built on the agent. So far I cannot isolate the issue.

Comment: What is the version of `System.ValueTuple` nuget package you are using? Have you tried downgrade the System.ValueTuple Nuget package to 4.3.0?

Comment: I'm not using `System.ValuTuple`. Why should I? I did try to add it as explained in the question but the issue remained.

Comment: It seems related to the .net 4.7.1 on the VS17 agent, https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/543, try to use private agent instead.

Comment: Thank you but saying to use a private agent doesn't really add value here.